# Cant click this button via xpath

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I cant click this button neither class or full xpath
my cde:

```
#checkout page

driver.get("https://www.theathletesfoot.gr/pages/checkout/default.aspx?lang=el")

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/section/form/aside/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/label").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you copied the XPath of the label, instead copy the XPath of the input right above the selected span in your screenshot and replace the XPath in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath should be

```
//*[@id="chkDisclaimer2"]
```